# Show price from product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, price

On the homepage i have categories with description and 2 latest added products from that specific category.

Now i have it working to display 2 products per category with image and productname but i can't get it working to show the product price also.

This is my code now:

```
<?php
    $_categoryId = explode(' ', $category['id']);

    $count = 0;

    $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryId)
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setOrder('date_added', 'ASC');
    ?>

    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>

        <?php
            $count++; // Note that first iteration is $count = 1 not 0 here.
            if($count <= 3) continue; // Skip the iteration unless 4th or above.
        ?>

        <li class="category-row-list-item">

            <a class="product-name" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>
            </a>

        </li>
        <?php
            if($count == 6) break;
        ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code for price where you want to display it.

`echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_product->getFinalPrice());`

Answer (score 1):

Hello You can show price by below code

`echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice);`

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i've used the first answer on this question

Comment: Should it be: `$_product->getPrice()`

Answer (score 0):

kindly add price attribute to your collection.

```
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
```

and then add

```
$_product->getPrice();
```

for show price with out formatting, And if you want to show it with currently you need to add code

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice(), true, false);?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i've used the first answer on this question

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

for price rendering price in case if your template uses Mage_Catalog_Block_Product block

If not you can use

```
 <?php echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product')->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this one doesn't work in my case, i've tried but it stays blank :(